# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null error. My script is at the end of the body, why am I still getting this error?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My script is at the end of the body, which has been the basic answer I've seen given when searching for a solution.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to use async/await?  I've written almost this exact code before, and its worked.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body id="body">
    <h1 id="header">Pokemon</h1>
    <div id="main-container">

    </div>
    <button id="button">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let pokemon = document.querySelectorAll('.poke');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let container = document.getElementById('main-container');


function loadPokemon() {
    const urs = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            const poke = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            container.innerHTML+= `
            ${poke.results.map(function(pok, index) {
                return `
                <div class='poke'>
                    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${(index + 1).toString()}.png">
                    </img>
                    ${pok.name}
                </div>
                `
            })}
            `
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', urs, true);
    xhr.send();
};


button.addEventListener('click', loadPokemon);
```

Comment: Execute your code after document is loaded, [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/11719787)

Answer (score 0):

It is working here.. I did not make any changes to your code

```js
let pokemon = document.querySelectorAll('.poke');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let container = document.getElementById('main-container');


function loadPokemon() {
    const urs = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            const poke = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            container.innerHTML+= `
            ${poke.results.map(function(pok, index) {
                return `
                <div class='poke'>
                    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${(index + 1).toString()}.png">
                    </img>
                    ${pok.name}
                </div>
                `
            })}
            `
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', urs, true);
    xhr.send();
};


button.addEventListener('click', loadPokemon);
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body id="body">
    <h1 id="header">Pokemon</h1>
    <div id="main-container">

    </div>
    <button id="button">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Are you sure you copy and pasted the exact code?

Comment: Yes, I'm going crazy here lol.  Its still not working for me.